# What model/approach to use to relate space and objects in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to play a little with django so I've started to create a "solution" to an old problem I have.
My background at OO programming and models relation is not that much so I ask for ideas/paths/solutions on how to achieve my goals.

My problem:

- I need to define spatial objects and relate them
  ex: Building 1, inside we have floor 1 and 2, inside floor 2 we have room A and B
- At each type of "location" I will place "things"
  ex: place 1 camera at building 1; place 1 camera at floor 2; place 1 camera at room B
- So I can archive the results bellow:
  Building 1: 3 cameras
  floor 2: 2 cameras
  room B: 1 camera

I was planning to archieve this using the old method of a table for each kind of object (building, floor, room) but I'm a little stuck on how to deal with diferent stuff the same way (actions) specialy because after dealing with this I have to put "people" at the equation, ie, I can put person J at room 2 and put a camera on him.

I thank you all in advance on all the thoughts (even if it is to say forget it and code it) because I a little lost here :)

Sorry if this is not the correct way (1st post):
@Amun_Re
I'm not that good with words, specially in English. The models you posted where my first database object relation, but after discovering the many to many relation I was thinking (and because I need to put objects in room and floor and building and they are differente) that django/python had a better way to deal with this.
I'll try to post an image of what I have designed for this phase.

Well, after rethinking all the things I'm trying an OO perspective. If they are going to be treated as same, they at least need to have come from the same place.
Right now I have a class "object" that all other classes inherit from (building, floor, person,...) but right now I have an issue, when I try to place a person on a building I get the error:

```
from django.db import models
from numpy import source
from objects.models import Asset, Object
# Create your models here.

class UseType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class Placement(models.Model):
    my_usetype = models.ForeignKey(UseType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    my_source = models.ForeignKey(Object, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    my_destination = models.ForeignKey(Object, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.created)
```

Can I even do this? Or should I use only integer fields instead of the foreighkeys and update then on a form only?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
class Placement(models.Model):
my_usetype = models.ForeignKey(UseType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
my_source = models.ForeignKey(Object, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='source')
my_destination = models.ForeignKey(Object, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='destination')
```

Just add the related_name :)

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with this:

models.py:

```
class Building(models.Model):
    #Building 1, 2 etc... Use Charfield if you want string name
    building_name = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.building_name)
    
class Room(models.Model):
    #One Building can have many rooms -> One to many relationship -> Foreignkey
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room_name = models
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.room_name)

#Since you want to put items such as camera on Objects (person can also be an object):
class ObjectInRoom(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room)
    object_in_room_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.object_in_room_name)

#Items such as camera etc. 
class ItemOnObject(models.Model):
    object_in_room = models.ForeignKey(ObjectInRoom, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_on_object_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.item_on_object_name)
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Building, Room, ObjectInRoom, ItemOnObject
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Building)
admin.site.register(Room)
admin.site.register(ObjectInRoom)
admin.site.register(ItemOnObject)
```

Don't forget to make migrations using `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` in your console.

You can test your models by running the server with `python manage.py runserver` and logging in to `/admin`. If you haven't already, create a superuser in order to be able to log in to the admin site using `python manage.py createsuperuser`.

Comment: Thank you Amun_Re, that was a little like my first approach. Sorry, still trying to figure how things work at stackoverflow :)

Comment: Hi Raul, same here, still quite new. It is best practice to edit the original question if it needs an update / clarification. For example, you could add the picture of your relational draft in the above question.

Answer (score 0):

[relational draft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQeGb.png)

The image above is my first design, now I changed it a little becuase I found some "stuff/library" that work different in python/django.

Let me try to explain my doubts a little better:
Is there a way to relate objects (like a camera) with other different kind of objects (building, room, person) without the need to add extra code for that?

NOTE: Because I just open the account there are a lot of stuff I can't do :) sorry for messing a little my own question.